# MySQL Select limit for pagination

Tags: mysql, select, join, pagination, unique

I have a result of select from my table:

```
id  tag
1   hey
1   wow
2   cry
87   game
87   bmw
6   lady
7   wow
```

But this result I getting with JOIN.
My full SQL query:

```
SELECT sites.id, sites.host, sites.url, sites.password, sites.status, sites.pr, sites.tyc, sites.alexa, sites.lastcheck, sites.comment, tags.tagname, tags.tagid FROM sites
LEFT JOIN sites_tags ON sites_tags.shellid = sites.id 
LEFT JOIN tags ON sites_tags.tagid = tags.tagid
```

For pagination I need 3 actual datas from query.

If my query - LIMIT 3, I want to get

```
1   hey
1   wow
2   cry
87   game
87   bmw
```

but not

```
 1   hey
 1   wow
 2   cry
```

E.g. I need all result limited by ID, not by rows.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: The query you're giving doesn't yield the example datasets you're showing. Makes it difficult to understand what exactly you try to achieve.

Comment: Dont know if it is the best solution, but im used to make views for queries with multiple joins. No problems with limits, and also I can easily work with it on special ocasions when i need to check something directly in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    s.host, 
    s.url, 
    s.password, 
    s.status, 
    s.pr, 
    s.tyc, 
    s.alexa, 
    s.lastcheck, 
    s.comment, 
    tags.tagname, 
    tags.tagid 
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, 
        host, 
        url, 
        password, 
        status, 
        pr, 
        tyc, 
        alexa, 
        lastcheck, 
        comment
    FROM sites
    LIMIT 3
) s
LEFT JOIN sites_tags ON sites_tags.shellid = s.id 
LEFT JOIN tags ON sites_tags.tagid = tags.tagid
```

This assumes that what you are wanting is the tags that relate to precisely 3 sites.  This will select the site information for 3 sites, and then will also select any tag(s) if there are any.

However it will not return precisely what you want, you would be better pressed to do one query to select all the fields from `sites`

```
SELECT
    id, 
    host, 
    url, 
    password, 
    status, 
    pr, 
    tyc, 
    alexa, 
    lastcheck, 
    comment
FROM sites
LIMIT 3
```

and then a second to do the following to get the tags for those sites.

```
SELECT 
    sites_tags.shellid AS id, 
    tags.tagname, 
    tags.tagid 
FROM sites_tags
INNER JOIN tags ON sites_tags.tagid = tags.tagid
WHERE sites_tags.shellid IN (..... your ids go here ......)
```

Answer (score 1):

(guessing that `id` refers to `sites.id`)

Replace `FROM sites` with:

```
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM sites 
       ORDER BY whatever 
       LIMIT 3
     ) AS sites
```